# Specify GDB version for Termdebug

Tags: startup, debugging

I am trying to use `:Termdebug` in Vim 8.1 on a CentOS machine. The default version of GDB at `/usr/bin/gdb` is less than the required v7.12. However, I have newer versions of GDB within `devtoolset` distributions I have installed with `yum`. To enable newer GDB versions, I need to run `source /opt/rh/devtoolset-{version}/enable`.

I don't want to source that script in my `.bashrc` and disrupt my default environment. Is there anyway I can run that command on running `:Termdebug`?

Is this possible with `:TermdebugCommand`?

Comment: You could try setting the `g:termdebugger` variable to the gdb you want to run.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by [Christian](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt) (all credits to him) in [this comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17784/specify-gdb-version-for-termdebug#comment30561_17784), setting `g:termdebugger` does the trick. Put this into your .vimrc:

```
let g:termdebugger='/path/to/your/gdb'
```

Single quotes are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can always have a look at that `enable` script and interpret it if it's simple enough like setting a bunch of environment variables: `PATH=...;LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...`.

This is what I've done in an unpackaged plugin that wraps lmod `module`  command.

- The plugin file: https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/lmod.vim
- The autoload plugin file: https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/autoload/lh/lmod.vim -- this is where the *magic* happens

  - I execute `$LMOD_CMD` with the right context in order to extract what it returns (to be `eval`uated)
  - and then I parse all the assignments and convert them into `:let $VAR="value"`

(`module`  permits to work on complex environments (like HPC clusters) where numerous softwares, compilers, etc are installed. Some are compatible between them, some are not. With `module`  we can dynamically enable or disable what we need at a given time. On such systems, devtoolset scripts would be typically  converted into a lmod module script)